# CSV to Excel - preserving percentages using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to write a script that merge multiple CSV files into one Excel file with separate sheets. In doing so, I realized any column that has a percentage in it, will have the error `The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe`.  There are multiples columns in each sheet with no specific order that contain percentages, so I am looking for a solution that avoids the error for all columns containing a percentage. I have tried passing different parameters but they haven't solved the problem yet.

Here is a sample code of what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'Test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index = None, header=True)

writer.save()
```

I have included screenshots of the csv file and the excel file, so I hope it helps to better demonstrate the issue at hand. Just to be clear, this is only for the sake of presentation and not the actual files I am working with.

[image: CSV][image: Excel]

Comment: all column headers that you need to remove are `precentages` or different column names?

Comment: different column names

Answer (score 0):

you can add formats using [set_column](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column) to worksheet by accessing it.

```
data = {'Text':['This', 'Column', 'is filled', 'with'], 'Number':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Percentages':['23.3%','46.82%','1.28%','33.3%']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True, sheet_name='somename')
# get the workbook and worksheet
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['somename']
# add format (percentage with 2 decimals)
percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
# set 3rd column to percentage format
worksheet.set_column(2,2,12, percent_fmt)
writer.save()
```

Comment: I tried running this but the output shows the same error `The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe` as I mentioned before. Also, I am looking for a solution that can be applied to the whole workbook that does not involve finding columns with percentages, if possible. There are way too many columns in each sheet.